# LINQ select to new object, setting values of object in function

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am using `LINQ` to select a new `twoWords` object into a `List` of this objects, and set the values by calling a function/method.

Please see if this makes sense, I have simplified it a lot. I really want to use the linq statements `from` `select`.

The first function in `GOGO` will work, the second one fails (they do not perform the same task though)

```
// simple class containing two strings, and a function to set the values
public class twoWords
{
    public string word1 { get; set; }
    public string word2 { get; set; }

    public void setvalues(string words)
    {
        word1 = words.Substring(0,4);
        word2 = words.Substring(5,4);
    }
}

public class GOGO
{

    public void ofCourseThisWillWorks()
    {
        //this is just to show that the setvalues function is working
        twoWords twoWords = new twoWords();
        twoWords.setvalues("word1 word2");
        //tada. object twoWords is populated
    }

    public void thisdoesntwork()
    {
        //set up the test data to work with
        List<string> stringlist =  new List<string>();
        stringlist.Add("word1 word2");
        stringlist.Add("word3 word4");
        //end setting up

        //we want a list of class twoWords, contain two strings : 
        //word1 and word2. but i do not know how to call the setvalues function.
        List<twoWords> twoWords = (from words in stringlist 
                            select new twoWords().setvalues(words)).ToList();
    }
}
```

The second function of `GOGO` will cause an error :

> The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.

My question is, how do I select the new `twoWords` object in the above `from` clause, while setting the values using the `setvalues` function?

Comment: As an aside, it *really* helps readability if you follow .NET naming conventions even for simple sample code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use a statement lambda, which means not using a query expression. In this case I wouldn't use a query expression anyway, given that you've only got a select...

```
List<twoWords> twoWords = stringlist.Select(words => {
                                                var ret = new twoWords();
                                                ret.setvalues(words);
                                                return ret;
                                            })
                                    .ToList();
```

Or alternatively, just have a method which returns an appropriate `twoWords`:

```
private static twoWords CreateTwoWords(string words)
{
    var ret = new twoWords();
    ret.setvalues(words);
    return ret;
}

List<twoWords> twoWords = stringlist.Select(CreateTwoWords)
                                    .ToList();
```

This would also let you use a query expression if you really wanted to:

```
List<twoWords> twoWords = (from words in stringlist 
                           select CreateTwoWords(words)).ToList();
```

Of course another option would be to give `twoWords` a constructor which did the right thing to start with, at which point you wouldn't just need to call a method...

Comment: Thanks Jon. This will definitely work for my question. For interest sake, what if I did want to use a query expression, AND keep the twoWords class as is? Is this possible?

My actual select looks like this : 
            List<twoWords> twoWords = (from menu in xmlDoc.Descendants("MENU")
                            where (string)menu.Attribute("type") == menuType
                            from words in menu.Elements("item")
                            select new twoWords().setAttributes(words)
                            )
                            .ToList();

Comment: @DavidSmit: You can do it, but only with a helper method (as per the bottom part). Query expressions *only* allow expression lambdas.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the first example, it is missing ")" before ".ToList()", is that intentional?