# LINQ query to find Date difference?

Tags: c#, linq, date

I am having date details which is in format **(dd/mm/yyyy)** like,

Table #1

```
id  Name   date          User
--------------------------------
1   xxx  01/01/2016     user1
2   yyy  01/02/2016     user2
3   aaa  02/03/2016     user1
```

Table #2

```
id Name       date
--------------------
 1  xxx    07/01/2016
 2  xxx    09/01/2016
 3  yyy    05/02/2016
 4. aaa    04/03/2016
```

**EDIT 1:**
The logic is, For the First time the xxx occured in Table2 means, it gets the date from the Table1 to compute the day difference. For the next time xxx value occured means, it get thes the date from Table2 (not table1) Because the Table2 already have the value in that table.So the day difference will compute by using Table2 alone. Same for the other values too. 
**EDIT 2:**
Actually, I need to get the date difference for the value. I have to get the date difference by using Table1 if the Name is occurred First time. And to get the Dtae difference from Table2 , If the Name is occurred before.
I am having 'Name' field as UNIQUE
Result should be like,

```
 user Name       DateDifference
 ------------------------------------
 user1 xxx 6  (07/01/2016 - 01/01/2016)
 user1 xxx 2  (07/01/2016 - 09/01/2016)
 user2 yyy 4  (01/02/2016 - 05/02/2016)
 user1 aaa 2  (02/03/2016 - 04/03/2016)
```

LINQ query I have tried is,

```
var query = (from item1 in Table1
                join item2 in Table1 on item1.Name equals item2.Name
                where item2.Date > item1.Date
                join origin in Table2 on item1.Name equals origin.Name
                where // condition
                group new { item1,item2 } by new {  item1.Name,item1.Date } into grp
                select new
                {                   

                    DayDiff = DbFunctions.DiffDays(grp.Key.Date, grp.Min(d => d.item2.Date)),
                }
                ).ToList();
```

But I could not get the result expected. I am also aware of this question, [How to get the date difference by joining two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004210/how-to-get-the-date-difference-by-joining-two-tables) , But finally they did not end it in proper LINQ query option.

How my question differ from [How to get the date difference by joining two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004210/how-to-get-the-date-difference-by-joining-two-tables) ?
The answer is in SQL. I need to code it in LINQ.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793079/linq-select-to-new-object-setting-values-of-object-in-function

Comment: I will refer that, Thanks

Comment: You are storing datetime-strings or real datetimes?

Comment: **Type** : `datetime`

Comment: How my question differ from How to get the date difference by joining two tables? ? The answer is in SQL. I need to code it in LINQ.

Comment: It is not clear: at result's table you have two rows with xxx name, what about pair: 01/01/2016 - 09/01/2016, is it needed or not? And where you get 01/01/2016 value, may you meant 01/01/2015? Explain logic of getting desired result more carefully.

Comment: *I could not get the result expected* So what *do* you get?

Comment: I am also need to get the result. 'Concat' is useful to proceed ?

Comment: I am trying to concat the two tables but that does not gives the result. I did not get anything from that. That is just a try I made to write LINQ query. Kindly Please do correct it, if anything wrong in it.

Comment: It's hard to correct it if there's no clearance on what the desired result is. What constraints are there in your tables? Any unique fields? What is the relation between tables? What is your current result and what is wrong with it? What are the fields' datatypes in your entities.

Comment: Actually, I need to get the date difference for the value. I have to get the date difference by using Table1 if the Name is occurred First time. And to get the Dtae difference from Table2 , If the Name is occurred before.
I am having 'Name' field as UNIQUE

Comment: By using Table1 and Table2 need to get the result for "Day Difference". using concat (union all) merge the two tables and have to use the "daydiff" to get the difference of the date for the Name.
But i ma not sure about getting the day difference for the first time occurence

Comment: What will be, if we will have at Table #2 third xxx row? DateDifference will be computed between it value and 07/01/2016 or 09/01/2016?

Comment: Table 2 have Third xxx row with date  '11/01/2016' means , the day difference will be 2 (09/01/2016 - 11/01/2016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope at least you have navigation property over those two tables.Try this

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new aaContext2())
            {
                IList<DTO> dto = new List<DTO>();
                dto = db.Table2.Select(a => new DTO
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    User = a.Namea.User,
                    DateDifference = (DbFunctions.DiffDays(a.Date, db.Table2.Where(aa => aa.Name.Equals(a.Name) && a.Date < aa.Date).Min(dd => dd.Date)
                    ) ?? (DbFunctions.DiffDays(db.Table1.Where(aa => aa.Name.Equals(a.Name)).Min(aaa => aaa.Date), a.Date)))
                }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    public class DTO
    {
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? DateDifference { get; set; }
    }
    public class aaContext2 : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }

    }
    public class Table1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Table2> NameList { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }

    }
    public class Table2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Table1 Namea { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way:

```
var query =
    (from t1 in db.Table1
     join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.Name equals t2.Name
     let prevDate = (from t3 in db.Table2
                     where t3.Name == t2.Name && t3.Date < t2.Date
                     select (DateTime?)t3.Date).Max() ?? t1.Date
     select new
     {
        t1.User,
        t1.Name,
        DayDiff = DbFunctions.DiffDays(prevDate, t2.Date).Value,
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the date diff to be **inside where condition** not outside the query so this form helped me:

Found it on [forums.asp.net](https://forums.asp.net/t/1573350.aspx?LINQ%20to%20SQL%20Query%20Between%20Dates%20DOB%20s%20within%20next%2014%20days%20)

> Here's a sample showing one way to get all employees with a DOB between now and 14 days from now...
>
> ```
> var employeesWithBirthday = 
>     from emp in dc.Employees
>     let BirthdayDiff = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, emp.BirthDate.Month, emp.BirthDate.Day) - DateTime.Now).TotalDays 
>     where BirthdayDiff >= 0 && BirthdayDiff <= 14
>     select emp;
> ```
>
> ...although, be aware that a query like that will do a table scan (can't use any indexes)...